# Unable to save ArrayList value in Shared Preference in Andorid

Tags: java, android, json, sharedpreferences

Can any one help me whats wrong in my code 
unable to save ArrayList document value in shared Preference 
getting null value in Debug of Array List Document

please help me

Thanks in advance

here is my JSON response

```
{
   "errCode": 0,
   "message": "Success",
   "responseDestinationDocument": [
       {
           "name": "United Arab Emirates",
           "document": [
               {
                   "name": "Passport Front",
                   "id": "2",
                   "notes": [
                       {
                           "name": "Upload colored passport copies."
                       },
                       {
                           "name": "Passport should be valid 6 months from the date of entry in Sri Lanka."
                       },
                       {
                           "name": "DDDDDDD"
                       }
                   ]
               },
               {
                   "name": "Passport Back",
                   "id": "3",
                   "notes": [
                       {
                           "name": "Upload colored passport copy."
                       }
                   ]
               },
               {
                   "name": "Photograph",
                   "id": "4",
                   "notes": [
                       {
                           "name": "Upload photograph with white background"
                       }
                   ]
               }
           ]
       }
   ]
}
```

I want to save ArrayList document value in shared Preference

Here is activity code

```
  public class UploadDocumentsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private MyCustomAdapter myCustomAdapter;
    protected ViewDialog viewDialog;
    String destination_id, start_date, end_date, no_of_travellers, destination_name, package_id, radioSexButton, booking_id, count_index;
    private List<ResponseBookingDocument> responseBookingDocumentArrayList;
    private List<Document> document1ArrayList;
    Document document1;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView_Identity;
    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 100;
    private static final int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 123;

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
    private ImageView imageView1;
    String selectedImagePath;
    private Uri filePath_1;
    private boolean isOnTag = false;
    Bitmap bitmap;
   preivate ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();
   preivate ArrayList<String> idList = new ArrayList<>();


    TextView continueTextView;
    private Runnable mToast = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
//            documentRequiredCall();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };

    ResponseBookInfo responseBookInfo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_documents);
        viewDialog = new ViewDialog(this);
        viewDialog.setCancelable(false);


//        Log.e("document1", document1.getId() + "");

        try {

            document1 = PrefUtils.getDocId(UploadDocumentsActivity.this);

            Log.e("document1", document1.getId() + "");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Intent i = getIntent();

        destination_id = i.getStringExtra("destination_id");
        package_id = i.getStringExtra("package_id");
        radioSexButton = i.getStringExtra("radioSexButton");
        booking_id = i.getStringExtra("booking_id");
        count_index = i.getStringExtra("count_index");
        Log.e("BookING", booking_id + "");
        destination_name = i.getStringExtra("destination_name");

        start_date = i.getStringExtra("start_date");
        end_date = i.getStringExtra("end_date");
        no_of_travellers = i.getStringExtra("no_of_travellers");
        recyclerView_Identity = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_Identity);
        continueTextView = findViewById(R.id.continueTextView);


        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(UploadDocumentsActivity.this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView_Identity.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView_Identity.setHasFixedSize(true);

        continueTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(UploadDocumentsActivity.this, ApplicationFormActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("booking_id", booking_id);
                i.putExtra("count_index", count_index);
                i.putExtra("start_date", start_date);
                i.putExtra("end_date", end_date);

                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

        documentRequiredCall();

//

        Log.e("Values", destination_id + " " + package_id + " " + end_date + " " + no_of_travellers + "  " + count_index + "");
    }

    public void documentRequiredCall() {

        Call<DocumentFetchModel> call = RetrofitClient
                .getInstance().getApi().documentFetchModel(booking_id, count_index);

        showProgressDialog();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<DocumentFetchModel>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<DocumentFetchModel> call, retrofit2.Response<DocumentFetchModel> response) {
                final DocumentFetchModel documentFetchModel = response.body();
                hideProgressDialog();


                PrefUtils.setDocId(documentFetchModel.getResponseBookingDocument().get(0).getDocument(), UploadDocumentsActivity.this);

int size = documentFetchModel.getResponseBookingDocument().get(0).getDocument().size();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            nameList.add(documentFetchModel.getResponseBookingDocument().get(0).getDocument().get(i).getName());
idList.add(documentFetchModel.getResponseBookingDocument().get(0).getDocument().get(i).getId());
        }


//here is app preference class saving the values
AppPreference.setNameList(this, nameList);
 AppPreference.setIdList(this, idLIst);

                if (documentFetchModel.getErrCode().booleanValue() == true) {

                    responseBookingDocumentArrayList = new ArrayList<ResponseBookingDocument>();


                    try {

                        Log.e("Booking_Document", new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
                        document1ArrayList = documentFetchModel.getResponseBookingDocument().get(0).getDocument();

                        myCustomAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(document1ArrayList);
                        recyclerView_Identity.setAdapter(myCustomAdapter);
                        myCustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(UploadDocumentsActivity.this, documentFetchModel.getMessage() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<DocumentFetchModel> call, Throwable t) {

                hideProgressDialog();
                Toast.makeText(UploadDocumentsActivity.this, t.getMessage() + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e("Error", t.getMessage() + "");
            }
        });


    }

    protected void hideProgressDialog() {
        viewDialog.dismiss();
    }

    protected void showProgressDialog() {
        viewDialog.show();
    }

    protected void showProgressDialog(String message) {
        showProgressDialog();
    }



    public class MyCustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyCustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

        private List<Document> moviesList;

        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public TextView textTitle;
            public ImageView imageUpload, imageFetch;

            private List<Note> noteArrayList;
            private MyCustomAdapter2 myCustomAdapter2;
            private RecyclerView recyclerView_Identity_Bullets;

            public MyViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);

                textTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
                imageUpload = view.findViewById(R.id.imageUpload);
                imageFetch = view.findViewById(R.id.imageFetch);

                recyclerView_Identity_Bullets = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_Identity_Bullets);

                LinearLayoutManager layoutManager2 = new LinearLayoutManager(UploadDocumentsActivity.this);
                layoutManager2.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
                recyclerView_Identity_Bullets.setLayoutManager(layoutManager2);
                recyclerView_Identity_Bullets.setHasFixedSize(true);


            }

        }


        public MyCustomAdapter(List<Document> moviesList) {
            this.moviesList = moviesList;
        }

        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_upload_document, parent, false);

            return new MyCustomAdapter.MyViewHolder(itemView);
        }

        public void clear() {
            int size = this.moviesList.size();
            if (size > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    this.moviesList.remove(0);
                }

                this.notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, size);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {


            final Document datum = moviesList.get(position);


            holder.textTitle.setText(datum.getName() + "");

            holder.noteArrayList = datum.getNotes();
            holder.myCustomAdapter2 = new MyCustomAdapter2(holder.noteArrayList);
            holder.recyclerView_Identity_Bullets.setAdapter(holder.myCustomAdapter2);


            if (datum.getImageName().equals("")) {
                holder.imageFetch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.imageUpload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                holder.imageUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Toast.makeText(UploadDocumentsActivity.this, datum.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });


            } else {

                holder.imageUpload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.imageFetch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Picasso.with(UploadDocumentsActivity.this).load(datum.getImageName() + "").into(holder.imageFetch);


            }


        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return moviesList.size();
        }

    }

    public class MyCustomAdapter2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyCustomAdapter2.MyViewHolder> {

        private List<Note> moviesList;

        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public TextView textBullet;


            public MyViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);

                textBullet = view.findViewById(R.id.textBullet);

            }

        }


        public MyCustomAdapter2(List<Note> moviesList) {
            this.moviesList = moviesList;
        }

        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_upload_bullets_and_image, parent, false);

            return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
        }

        public void clear() {
            int size = this.moviesList.size();
            if (size > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    this.moviesList.remove(0);
                }

                this.notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, size);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {


            final Note datum = moviesList.get(position);


            holder.textBullet.setText(" \u25CF " + datum.getName() + "");

            Log.e("textBullet", datum.getName() + "");


        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return moviesList.size();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mToast.run();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        handler.removeCallbacks(mToast);
    }

}
```

Here is Model Class

```
public class DocumentFetchModel {

    @SerializedName("errCode")
    @Expose
    private Boolean errCode;
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("responseBookingDocument")
    @Expose
    private List<ResponseBookingDocument> responseBookingDocument = null;

    public Boolean getErrCode() {
        return errCode;
    }

    public void setErrCode(Boolean errCode) {
        this.errCode = errCode;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public List<ResponseBookingDocument> getResponseBookingDocument() {
        return responseBookingDocument;
    }

    public void setResponseBookingDocument(List<ResponseBookingDocument> responseBookingDocument) {
        this.responseBookingDocument = responseBookingDocument;
    }
}


public class ResponseBookingDocument {

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("document")
    @Expose
    private List<Document> document = null;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Document> getDocument() {
        return document;
    }

    public void setDocument(List<Document> document) {
        this.document = document;
    }

}
```

public class DocumentFetchModel {

```
   @SerializedName("errCode")
    @Expose
    private Boolean errCode;
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("responseBookingDocument")
    @Expose
    private List<ResponseBookingDocument> responseBookingDocument = null;

    public Boolean getErrCode() {
        return errCode;
    }

    public void setErrCode(Boolean errCode) {
        this.errCode = errCode;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public List<ResponseBookingDocument> getResponseBookingDocument() {
        return responseBookingDocument;
    }

    public void setResponseBookingDocument(List<ResponseBookingDocument> responseBookingDocument) {
        this.responseBookingDocument = responseBookingDocument;
    }
}
```

Here is ComplexPreference

```
public class ComplexPreferences {

    private static ComplexPreferences complexPreferences;
    private Context context;
    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private static Gson GSON = new Gson();
    Type typeOfObject = new TypeToken<Object>() {
    }.getType();

    private ComplexPreferences(Context context, String namePreferences, int mode) {
        this.context = context;
        if (namePreferences == null || namePreferences.equals("")) {
            namePreferences = "complex_preferences";
        }
        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(namePreferences, mode);
        editor = preferences.edit();
    }

    public static ComplexPreferences getComplexPreferences(Context context,
                                                           String namePreferences, int mode) {

//      if (complexPreferences == null) {
        complexPreferences = new ComplexPreferences(context,
                namePreferences, mode);
//      }

        return complexPreferences;
    }

    public void putObject(String key, Object object) {
        if(object == null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("object is null");
        }

        if(key.equals("") || key == null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("key is empty or null");
        }

        editor.putString(key, GSON.toJson(object));
    }

    public void commit() {
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void clearObject() {
        editor.clear();
    }

    public <T> T getObject(String key, Class<T> a) {

        String gson = preferences.getString(key, null);
        if (gson == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            try{
                return GSON.fromJson(gson, a);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Object storaged with key " + key + " is instanceof other class");
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Here is PrefUtils Class

```
public class PrefUtils {
  public static DocumentFetchModel getDoc(Context ctx) {
        ComplexPreferences complexPreferences = ComplexPreferences.getComplexPreferences(ctx, "get_doc", 0);
        DocumentFetchModel currentUser = complexPreferences.getObject("docs", DocumentFetchModel.class);
        return currentUser;
    }

    public static void setDoc(DocumentFetchModel currentUser, Context ctx) {
        ComplexPreferences complexPreferences = ComplexPreferences.getComplexPreferences(ctx, "get_doc", 0);
        complexPreferences.putObject("docs", currentUser);
        complexPreferences.commit();
    }

    }
```

Comment: you can put only SET in shared preference not ArrayList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can save list in sharedpreference like this:-

```
    public class AppPreferences {
                    private static SharedPreferences mPrefs;
                    private static SharedPreferences.Editor mPrefsEditor;

                    public static Set<String> getName(Context ctx) {
        mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        return mPrefs.getStringSet("nameList", null);
    }

    public static void setName(Context ctx, ArrayList<String> value) {
        mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        mPrefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.addAll(value);
        mPrefsEditor.putStringSet("nameList", set);
        mPrefsEditor.commit();
    }

public static void clearNameList(Context ctx) {
       mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        mPrefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
        mPrefsEditor.putStringSet("nameList", set);
        mPrefsEditor.commit();
    }
            }
```

to set list :-

```
setCamEval(activity, list);
```

to get list :-

```
getCamEval(this);
```