# How to declare list global ?? want to use in fragment from adapter

Tags: java, android

I have list in my adapter, in that I have saved id of checkbox , I want to use that list in fragment..

```
public static List<String> mUseritems = new ArrayList<>(); 
public static List<String> portalnames = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Use it like adapter.mUseritems

Comment: use gson for this to save and retrieve back here is example
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384064/gson-convert-from-json-to-a-typed-arraylistt

Answer (score 0):

you can set you both list in you activity and then you can access your both list in your adapter or in fragment or there is another way to get you list in all the project you can save your list in shared preference and get you list where you want :-

you can follow this link to save your list in preference :-

[Unable to save ArrayList value in Shared Preference in Andorid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55756579/unable-to-save-arraylist-value-in-shared-preference-in-andorid/55756645#55756645)

Answer (score 0):

Declare List in Parent Activity, And for accessing this list Typecast getActivity() with Parent

```
((ParentActivity) getActivity()).mUseritems;
```